# PHP Curl on a login private page

Tags: php, curl, cookies

I'm doing a php project that gets information from a private website (protected by login) and show. Now I want to use this private website pages, like click on settings, view, refresh... 
The problem is that I can only view the page, I cant do any action in the private website. How can I do this?

```
$captcha = $_REQUEST['g-recaptcha-response'];
$user_id = "xxxx";
$user_password = "xxxx"; 

$cookie_file_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/teste/cook";
$LOGINURL = "website/entrar/";
$agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0";
$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);


//Post Login Data to Page
$LOGINURL = "website/entrar/";
$POSTFIELDS = "login=$user_id&senha=$user_password&g-recaptcha-response=$captcha&lembrar=on&logar=";
$reffer = "website/entrar/";
$ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$LOGINURL);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$POSTFIELDS); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $reffer);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
    curl_exec ($ch);

//Pegar conteudo pagina
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "website/private");
    $html = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch); 
    print   $html;
```

Comment: Does the actual web page use Javascript and AJAX? If so, you'll need to emulate that.

Comment: curl cannot remote control a web page.  It can only perform http operations.